# Laravet test case failing, unable to run seed on test case

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

My test case:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker, DatabaseMigrations;

    protected $endPoint = '/dashboard/users';

    public function setUp():void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->artisan('migrate:fresh');
        $this->artisan('db:seed');
    }

    public function test_users_list_is_showing_correctly()
    {
        $this->signIn();
        $this->get($this->endPoint)
            ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

But, I am receiving error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: settings (SQL: select "id", "name", "setting_value" from "settings")
```

It might be throwing error because, I have this code in boot method of `AppServiceProvider`

```
config(['settings' => Setting::get(['id','name','setting_value'])]);
```

How to fix this? Its probably that migration and seeder are not working, but not sure.

Comment: `RefreshDatabase`  and `DatabaseMigrations` will both run the database migrations and you are also running them in your setup. Seems a bit of an overkill. It might also result in this error since running an artisan command will also run the service providers. I suggest using only `RefreshDatabase` and then seeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using laravel 8.x and as it can be seen in code that you have used **RefreshDatabase** trait. You can do something like this:

```
 // Run the DatabaseSeeder...
    $this->seed();

 // Run a specific seeder...
  $this->seed(OrderStatusSeeder::class);
```

The above code is taken from the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders).

Alternatively, you can set

```
protected $seed = true;
```

in your base test case class. This will run the seeder before each test that uses **RefreshDatabase** trait.

You can also define which seeder should run by specifying this

```
protected $seeder = OrderStatusSeeder::class;
```

in your test class.

Hope this helps. More information you find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders).

Comment: I have tried `$this->seed` as well but it is giving the same error, probably because, we have yet to run migration right? Or the migration will be run by default?

Comment: Ideally, you should create a separate database for testing. This can be done by creating .env.testing file and providing the test database connection details.

Then you can run migration with this command:

php artisan migrate --env´=testing

Then run the tests.

Comment: thank you, I fix this issue but I am facing this new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028539/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1-on-conflict-clause-does-not-match-any-primary could you please help on this one?