# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint error on test environment

Tags: php, laravel

I am using mysql on my laravel enviroment and I am using sqlite as database on `.env.testing`. I could easily run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` on laravel but if I run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --env=testing` I am getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
```

And my this particular seeder where it is throwing error looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PermissionsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Permission::upsert([
            /**
             * User Model Related Permissions 1-4
             */
            [
                'name' => 'user-view',
                'label' => 'User View',
                'description' => 'Allows to view users',
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'user-create',
                'label' => 'User Create',
                'description' => 'Allows to create user',
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'user-update',
                'label' => 'User Update',
                'description' => 'Allows to update user',
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'user-destroy',
                'label' => 'User Destroy',
                'description' => 'Allows to destroy user',
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ],
            
        ], ['name'], ['label','description','updated_at']);
    }
}
```

This same code in working on .env environment but not on `.env.testing` environment, but as I already mentioned `.env` is using mysql where as `.env.testing` is using `sqlite`